# Parsing xsl error- javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: use-character-maps attribute is not allowed on the xsl:output element

Tags: xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-2.0, saxparser, domparser

While parsing one of the XML files using XML Serializer in Java, the HTML entities are converted into their corresponding hex code values(like for mdash output is "hexcode value-#x2014;") and hence reflected into the final output file. In order to convert the hex code value to a normal entity, we tried an xsl transformation which throws an error as "javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: use-character-maps attribute is not allowed on the xsl:output element".

Below is the xsl used:-

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:character-map name="mdash">
<xsl:output-character character="&#x2014;" string="&amp;mdash;" />
</xsl:character-map>
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

We used a transformer factory object to transform the final XML to convert hex code into normal entities via xsl file.

Comment: Character maps were introduced in XSLT 2.0. The default Transformer in most Java JREs/JDKs is based on Xalan, which only supports XSLT 1.0. It is however easy in Java to put a release of Saxon 9 or 10 or (by now) 11 https://github.com/Saxonica/Saxon-HE/tree/main/11/Java or 12 https://github.com/Saxonica/Saxon-HE/tree/main/12/Java on the classpath to have XSLT 2 or 3 support

Comment: importing saxon jar to classpath resolved this error.

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests to me that you are trying to run an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet using an XSLT 1.0 processor.

Technically if the stylesheet says version="2.0", an XSLT 1.0 processor is supposed to run in "forwards compatibility mode", which is supposed to ignore any elements and attributes it doesn't understand (like `use-character-maps`) rather than raising an error. But I'm not sure that's always implemented correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments by Martin.
Importing saxon jar to classpath and using the TransformerFactory object as below fixed this error:-

```
TransformerFactory tfactory = new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl();
```